# ¿Como hacer una columna que sea scrolleable y que conserve sus propiedades MainAxis y CrossAxis?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

un saludo a todos los de la comunidad, ire directo al grano.

Quiero que una columna que sea scrolleable (benditos modismos), pero que conserve las propiedades de la columna (CrossAxis y MainAxis), siempre que anido la columna dentro de SingleChildScrollView se pierden esas propiedades y los elementos se colocan todos hacia arriba...

He tratado de solucionarlo colocando SizedBox entre los elementos pero no soluciona el problema cuando llevo la App a otro dispositivo con diferentes 
resoluciones y lo mismo sucede con el ListView.

Les doy las gracias de antemano y que tengan buen día.

```
body: Center(
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(          
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, 
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,right: 10.0),
            child: LogoCompleto(),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 170.0,),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            child: _viewCardRecibirDinero(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen de como se ve antes y despues del SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: Se me hace poco difícil lo de la imagen... lo siento, pero te describo lo que se ve cuando no uso el SingleChildScrollView, cuando el móvil está en portrait (orientación de la pantalla) no hay problema, pero cuando giro el móvil a landscape sale el mensaje de que ha sobre pasado el margen máximo del dispositivo (la cinta amarilla con negro), una de las soluciones es deshabilitar el modo landscape pero no quiero limitarme por no saber hacer las cosas... he probado de distintas maneras pero no logro hacerlo bien... otra manera usar el MediaQuery pero no logrado usarlo correctamente...

Comment: Entonces el problema es solo landscape? Eso no dice en tu pregunta. Para que sea mas clara agrega una imagen, toma capturas del simulador o dispositivo, editas la pregunta y adjuntas la imagen